# App keeps stopping in android studio emulator, no visible errors

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

When i try to launch the app on my Pixel 4 API 31 it keeps stopping. It starts and throws me out of the app, not even going to the start. I don't recognize visible errors. Here is my code:

Main activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.ecomap00.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home -> {
                textView.setText("Home")
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.nav_search -> {
                textView.setText("Search")
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.nav_add_post -> {
                textView.setText("Add post")
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.nav_notifications -> {
                textView.setText("Notifications")
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.nav_profile -> {
                textView.setText("Profile")
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }

        false
    }



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.message)
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)


    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My bottom_nav_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_add_post"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/heart"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon"
        android:title="" />

</menu>
```

I also have a couple of still empty xml files that I will use later, I don't know if that could be the reason. If someone could tell what the problem is I would be glad to know.

edit: Thank you guys the problem was the setContentView()

Comment: Post a stacktrace at least. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Answer (score 1):

It is crashing because, you are not setting any `view` to your `activity` and trying to find the `text` and `bottomNav`, add `setContentView` in `oncreate` after `super` call

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    textView = findViewById(R.id.message)
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing setContentView() method for your activity, so it can not find your view like TextView...
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(int)